# undefined value in nested input with react hook form

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox, nested

I have to do nested checkboxes so that if the parent is checked, the children are automatically checked, but there is also the possibility to check juste some of the children. 
(There are multiple nested levels)

So I made custom checkboxes, on submit I get the keys of the children but the values are all undefined. 
Also the nested checkboxes are in collapses and they have to be open to get the keys on submit otherwise I don't get anything at all. (maybe when the collapse in closed there is a display: none ?

my form :

```
import { ChapterCheckbox } from "./ChapterCheckbox";
import { groupedRights } from "./groupedRights";
import translate from "@kpt/ui/providers/i18n/translateService";
import { grey } from "@kpt/ui/theme/colors";
import { Box, Button, Checkbox, CircularProgress, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import useUserRights from "applications/Users/Api/usePostUserRights";
import { Controller, FormProvider, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export type IChaptersProps = {
  chapter: string;
  titles: string[];
};
export interface IGroupedRightsProps {
  functionnality: string;
  name: string;
  chapters: IChaptersProps[];
}

export const RightsGenerator = () => {
  const methods = useForm({ reValidateMode: "onChange" });
  const { rights, isLoading, isError } = useUserRights("user");

  rights && console.log("rights", rights.results.datas, isError);

  return (
    <Box
      display="flex"
      flexDirection="column"
      alignItems="center"
      p={4}
      gap={3}
      height="100%"
      overflow="auto"
    >
      <Typography component="h3" variant="h6">
        Formulaire des droits utilisateurs
      </Typography>
      <Typography component="h4" variant="body1" sx={{ textDecoration: "underline" }}>
        Fonctionnalités
      </Typography>
      <Box width="100%">
        <FormProvider {...methods}>
          <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
            <Box display="flex" gap={2} justifyContent="space-around">
              <Box display="grid" gridTemplateColumns="1fr 1fr" alignItems="start" gap={2}>
                {isLoading ? (
                  <CircularProgress />
                ) : (
                  groupedRights(rights?.results.datas).map((data, i) => {
                    if (data.chapters.length === 1)
                      return (
                        <Box
                          height="fit-content"
                          py={1}
                          px={2}
                          border={`1px solid ${grey.main}`}
                          borderRadius="10px"
                          width={300}
                          key={`${data.functionnality}-${i}`}
                        >
                          <Controller
                            render={({ field }) => (
                              <FormControlLabel
                                {...field}
                                disableTypography
                                control={<Checkbox sx={{ color: grey.light }} />}
                                label={
                                  <Typography component="p" variant="body2">
                                    {data.functionnality}
                                  </Typography>
                                }
                              />
                            )}
                            name={data.functionnality}
                            control={methods.control}
                          />
                        </Box>
                      );
                    else
                      return (
                        <ChapterCheckbox
                          key={`${data.functionnality}-${i}`}
                          chapters={data.chapters}
                          functionnality={data.functionnality}
                          name={data.name}
                        />
                      );
                  })
                )}
              </Box>
              <Box
                display="flex"
                flexDirection="column"
                gap={2}
                sx={{ "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": { borderRadius: "10px" } }}
              >
                <TextField
                  id="outlined-basic"
                  label="Code Droits Utilisateurs"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value="test"
                />
                <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Nom du code" variant="outlined" value="test" />
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  variant="contained"
                  size="medium"
                  sx={{ borderRadius: "10px", width: "100%" }}
                >
                  {translate("app.constants.validate")}
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </form>
        </FormProvider>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

the data I map in the form (and that comes from the back api) :

```
import { IGroupedRightsProps } from ".";
import { IDatasProps } from "applications/Users/Domain/getUserRightsInterfaces";

export const groupedRights = (rights: IDatasProps[]) => {
  const sortedRights = rights?.sort((a, b) => {
    const nameA = a.description.split("_")[0];
    const nameB = b.description.split("_")[0];

    return nameA.localeCompare(nameB);
  });

  const groupedData: IGroupedRightsProps[] = sortedRights.reduce((result, obj) => {
    const functionnality = obj.function;
    const existingFunctionnality = result.find((group) => group.functionnality === functionnality);
    const split =
      obj.description.indexOf("_") === -1
        ? ["", ""]
        : obj.description.substring(obj.description.indexOf("_") + 1).split("_");

    const [chapter, title] = split;
    console.log(obj.description.substring(obj.description.indexOf("_") + 1), chapter, title);

    if (existingFunctionnality) {
      const existingChapter = existingFunctionnality.chapters.find((chap) => chap.chapter === chapter);

      if (existingChapter) {
        existingChapter.titles.push(title);
      } else {
        existingFunctionnality.chapters.push({
          chapter: chapter,
          titles: [title],
        });
      }
    } else {
      result.push({
        functionnality: functionnality,
        name: obj.name,
        chapters: [
          {
            chapter: chapter,
            titles: [title],
          },
        ],
      });
    }

    return result;
  }, []);

  console.log(groupedData);

  return groupedData;
};
```

the data looks like something like that :

```
{

    "name": "user.Relations.Hierarchy.Collaboration",

    "description": "Relations_Hiérarchie_Collaboration",

    "function": "Relations",

    "allowedAccountsType": ["user"]

  }
```

if they are children on the first nested checkbox :

```
import { IGroupedRightsProps } from ".";
import { PersonnalizedCheckbox } from "./PersonnalizedCheckbox";
import { TitleCheckbox } from "./TitleCheckbox";
import { grey } from "@kpt/ui/theme/colors";
import ExpandLess from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess";
import ExpandMore from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";
import { Collapse } from "@mui/material";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { useState } from "react";

export const ChapterCheckbox = ({ ...props }: IGroupedRightsProps) => {
  const [checkedChapters, setCheckedChapters] = useState(Array.from(props.chapters, () => false));
  const [openChapter, setOpenChapter] = useState(false);

  const handleChangeParentChapters = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const setAllEvent = Array.from(props.chapters, () => event.target.checked);
    setCheckedChapters(setAllEvent);
  };
  const handleChangeChapters = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, index: number) => {
    const updatedChecked = checkedChapters.map((item, i) => (i === index ? event.target.checked : item));
    setCheckedChapters(updatedChecked);
  };

  const allChaptersChecked = checkedChapters.every((item) => item === true);

  return (
    <Box border={`1px solid ${grey.main}`} borderRadius="10px" width={300}>
      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center" py={1} px={2}>
        <PersonnalizedCheckbox
          checked={allChaptersChecked}
          handleChange={handleChangeParentChapters}
          index={props?.functionnality.length}
          text={props.functionnality}
          indeterminate={!allChaptersChecked && checkedChapters.some((item) => item === true)}
        />
        <Box
          onClick={() => setOpenChapter(!openChapter)}
          borderRadius="10px"
          sx={{ cursor: "pointer", ":hover": { bgcolor: grey.extraLight } }}
        >
          {openChapter ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <Collapse in={openChapter} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" ml={3}>
          {props?.chapters.map((chapter, indexChapter) => {
            if (chapter.titles.length === 1)
              return (
                <PersonnalizedCheckbox
                  checked={checkedChapters[indexChapter]}
                  handleChange={(event) => handleChangeChapters(event, indexChapter)}
                  index={indexChapter}
                  text={chapter?.chapter}
                />
              );
            else
              return (
                <TitleCheckbox
                  chapter={chapter}
                  chapters={props?.chapters}
                  indexChapter={indexChapter}
                  checkedChapters={checkedChapters}
                />
              );
          })}
        </Box>
      </Collapse>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Children of children :

```
import { IChaptersProps } from ".";
import { PersonnalizedCheckbox } from "./PersonnalizedCheckbox";
import { grey } from "@kpt/ui/theme/colors";
import ExpandLess from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess";
import ExpandMore from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";
import { Collapse } from "@mui/material";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { useState } from "react";

export interface ITitleCheckboxProps {
  indexChapter: number;
  chapter: IChaptersProps;
  checkedChapters: boolean[];
  chapters: IChaptersProps[];
}

export const TitleCheckbox = ({ ...props }: ITitleCheckboxProps) => {
  const [openTitle, setOpenTitle] = useState(false);
  const [checkedTitles, setCheckedTitles] = useState(
    props.chapters.map((chapter) => Array.from(chapter.titles, () => false)),
  );

  const handleChangeParentTitles = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const setAllEvent = props.chapters.map((chapter) =>
      Array.from(chapter.titles, () => event.target.checked),
    );
    setCheckedTitles(setAllEvent);
  };
  const handleChangeTitles = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    indexChapter: number,
    indexTitle: number,
  ) => {
    const updatedCheckedTitles = checkedTitles.map((chapter, index) => {
      if (index === indexChapter) {
        const updatedTitles = chapter.map((title, titleIndex) =>
          titleIndex === indexTitle ? event.target.checked : title,
        );
        return updatedTitles;
      }
      return chapter;
    });
    setCheckedTitles(updatedCheckedTitles);
  };

  return (
    <Box key={`checkbox-children${props?.indexChapter}`}>
      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center" pr={2}>
        <PersonnalizedCheckbox
          checked={
            props?.checkedChapters[props?.indexChapter] ||
            checkedTitles[props?.indexChapter].every((item) => item === true)
          }
          indeterminate={
            !checkedTitles[props?.indexChapter].every((item) => item === true) &&
            checkedTitles[props?.indexChapter].some((item) => item === true)
          }
          handleChange={handleChangeParentTitles}
          index={props?.indexChapter}
          text={props?.chapter?.chapter}
        />
        <Box
          onClick={() => setOpenTitle(!openTitle)}
          borderRadius="10px"
          sx={{ cursor: "pointer", ":hover": { bgcolor: grey.extraLight } }}
        >
          {openTitle ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <Collapse in={openTitle} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" ml={3}>
          {props?.chapter.titles.map((title, indexTitle) => {
            return (
              <PersonnalizedCheckbox
                checked={
                  props?.checkedChapters[props?.indexChapter] ||
                  checkedTitles[props?.indexChapter][indexTitle]
                }
                handleChange={(e) => handleChangeTitles(e, props?.indexChapter, indexTitle)}
                index={indexTitle}
                text={title}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Box>
      </Collapse>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Generic Component use for the checkbox inputs :

```
import { grey } from "@kpt/ui/theme/colors";
import { Checkbox, FormControlLabel, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { Controller, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

export interface IParentCheckboxProps {
  index: number;
  text: string;
  checked: boolean;
  handleChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  indeterminate?: boolean;
}

export const PersonnalizedCheckbox = ({ ...props }: IParentCheckboxProps) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();
  return (
    <Controller
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormControlLabel
          {...field}
          disableTypography
          key={`checkbox-${props?.text}-${props?.index}`}
          label={
            <Typography component="p" variant="body2">
              {props?.text}
            </Typography>
          }
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={props?.checked}
              onChange={props?.handleChange}
              indeterminate={props?.indeterminate}
              sx={{ color: grey.light }}
            />
          }
        />
      )}
      name={props?.text}
      control={control}
    />
  );
};
```

So, it is pretty complicated.
Like I said, when the collapses are open I got the keys of the nested checkboxes but not the value.

I'll really appreciate any help because I'm completely stuck right now...

Thank you very much.